# Does attack type influence status effect build-up and application?

Tags: elden-ring

I have a Morning Star that says it causes "Blood Loss Buildup (50)" as a passive effect.

[image: Inventory view of Morning Star stats]

The Morning Star and its passive effect are just an example. This question is about all types of status effect application.

I understand the basics of how status effects work. This weapon applies 50 "blood loss points" to an enemy, and if that enemy has 100 Robustness (blood loss resistance), then it will take two hits from this weapon to afflict that enemy with the blood loss status effect.

My question is how weapons like this interact with different attack types. Is the blood loss buildup always a flat 50 no matter what type of attack is performed?

In other words, does holding this weapon two-handed increase the buildup? Do R2 hits cause more blood loss buildup? Do fully charged R2 hits cause even more? How about backstabs/criticals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: there is no difference between all regular not critical attacks in applying status effects.

---

**Tests:**

I did my tests in NG+, I tried to attack [Elder Dragon Greyoll](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Elder+Dragon+Greyoll) in Caelid and counted hits until first status damage proc, then rested on the nearest grace and tried again. I used 5 different weapons dealing from 50 to 105 either bleed or frost damage according to stats page. According to wiki this Dragon has 575 status resistance to both, but I'm not sure if this data is true for NG+. I used all types of attacks - one-handed (1H) and two-handed (2H), light (R1) and strong (R2), for strong attacks I also tried to fully charge each, and for 1H R1 attacks I tried to pause after each hit to match pace of slower strong attacks.

**Results:**

This table contains number of hits needed to trigger status effect damage with each weapon with each attack type.

| Weapon (Status DMG) | 1H R1 | 2H R1 | 1H R1 Slow | 1H R2 | 2H R2 | 1H R2 Charged | 2H R2 Charged |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Morning Star](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Morning+Star) (50 Bleed) | 15 | 15 | 17 | 17 | 17 | 18 | 18 |
| [Dark Moon Greatsword](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Dark+Moon+Greatsword) +10 (55 Frost) | 14 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 16 | 17 | 18 |
| Blood [Morning Star](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Morning+Star) (57 Bleed) | 13 | 13 | 15 | 14 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| Blood [Miséricorde](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Misericorde) +25 (83 Bleed) | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 10 | 10 |
| Cold [Miséricorde](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Misericorde) +25 (105 Frost) | 7 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 7 |

**Conclusion:**

All tested attacks deal the same amount of status damage, it's clearly seen on faster Miséricorde tests - it's a dagger class weapon and strong attacks are almost as fast as light attacks.

On slower weapons we see that it takes more strong attacks to trigger status effect. However, this could be explained by status buildup decay over time. When slowing down with light attacks, number of hits needed matches strong attacks. Charged attacks took even more time, hence more hits needed because of decay.